# Как перебрать коллекцию List на kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, list, коллекции

Есть коллекция List, с названием Task:

```
data class Task(
val id: Int,
val number: String,
val time: Long?,
val r: List<RaRa>,
val status: String
```

)

При вызове Toast:

```
override fun submitList(list: List<Task>) {    
        Toast.makeText(context, list[1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Получаю следующее сообщение:

> Task(id=1, number=6, time = 123456, r=[RaRa(loc=Moscow, index=0,
>   one=1.1, two=2.2, second=null)],status=NonStarted)

Как можно перебрать List и получить для каждого id из Task значения из Rara - one и two?

Comment: это не код, а то, что записано в коллекции list: List<Task>

Comment: тогда вам нужно обратится к исходному коду Task и поискать там. Потому что сейчас вопрос таков: у меня есть какая-то непонятная хрень (и я вам ее не покажу), как мне из нее взять, то что нужно.

Comment: `list.forEach { task -> task.r.forEach { rara -> println("one=${rara.one} two=${rara.two}" }` оно?

Comment: Тут Task, там UiTask и структура не совпадает. Но вообще используйте геттеры.

Comment: @IR42 это то, что нужно! Спасибо! Но, простите, за, скорее всего глупый вопрос, как я могу записать данные, которые получаю от println в переменные, чтобы не перезаписывались? Или в один массив?

Comment: @АзатСагутдинов нужно получить `List<Pair<Double, Doube>>` где `one` и `two` в паре из всех `task` и их `r` или нужно получить `List<Double>`, где все one и two в одной куче? или вообще что-то другое?

Comment: @IR42 я думаю, второй вариант, но чтобы one и two были попарно. Суть в том, что мне значения one и two нужно будет подставлять строчку попарно, то есть следующего вида: one, two~one, two  и т.д.
Может быть их сразу можно записать в какой-то массив в таком виде, чтобы парсить потом не нужно было?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функцию map из [Collections.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt)

```
list.map { task - > task.id }
```